# Accordion-like states on AngularJS with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to accomplish something that seems easy at first glance, but ends up being quite the challenge. I have an accordion-like section of an app, where each accordion item should open a child state when activated, with a few extra requirements:

1. child states can (and should) be the same child state, with different parameters.
2. child states are not know up-front, they're loaded dynamically.
3. deeplinking to a child state should work as expected. The accordion item expanded and the proper content loaded.

The idea is easy, there should be one child state, which loads/shows different data depending on the passed parameter, but the template of that child state should be place in the activated accordion item, not in one fixed place.

I partially tried the multiple named views option from ui-router, but doesn't look promising, since it would actually load all those named views at the same time. Plus, I need them to by dynamic, and even though is possible to define states dynamically with for example with [Future states](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future), it doesn't seem to be the right choice here.

Right now, I can only see 2 options:

1. Re-parent the ui-view inside the desired accordion item (didn't work at first try but did if I re-parent the container of the ui-view) but has buggy side-effects right after the testing, and I fear some critical side effect later. Basically the parent controller get's reloaded for a second time, keeping the previous instance in memory. Plus i've seen some duplicated DOM content in places outside the scope of even the parent. I don't like this approach of course, but has the advantage of actually placing the content I need inside the container I need.
2. Leave the ui-view outside the accordion, position absolute-it, and manage it's position based on the current state when navigating. The position absolute is not a big deal, but I need to keep measuring the content's height, and dynamically set the height of the expanded accordion item to make it look like it's inside of it :S. To make things more difficult, I'll probably have to place some complex rules to position this correctly for the responsive design this needs.

In the end, it's a route/code hack vs a visual hack. I'm taking the visual hack since it sounds safer, but it's definitely going to be more work. Any other approach or comments will be *highly* appreciated.

-- Edit --

There's a better option at least for the 2 options I had in mind: create the different child states (1 child state, with params) but not associate it with a template. Just leave all the DOM in the parent state/view, and manage visibility with ng-if

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about the option to use only one child state for all this and pass the additional information you need using parameters of the state?

so have URL-paramter for the accordion-section-id you want to open and other parameters for the different data to show.

Then open the correct accordion-section based on the stateParamter. Write a directive with private scope to render the content of the section and in each accordion reuse the same directive and pass it the correct data.

Then if the user clicks to open another accordion section, instead of the normal 'open'-action use a `$state.go('myState, {accordion-id: 'newidtoopen', datatoShow: dataids})`.